# ConcurrentHashMap<String, Ref> vs AtomicReference<Map<String, Ref>>

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

What is better to choose and why? The map is used as temporary storage. It keeps items for some time and then flush to db.

Here is dummy code I implemented with atomic reference:

```
public class Service {
    private final AtomicReference<Map<String, Entity>> storedEntities = new AtomicReference<>(new HashMap<>());
    private final AtomicReference<Map<String, Entity>> newEntities = new AtomicReference<>(new HashMap<>());

    private final Dao dao;

    public Service(Dao dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }

    @Transactional
    @Async
    public CompletableFuture<Void> save() {
        Map<String, Entity> map = newEntities.getAndSet(new HashMap<>());
        return dao.saveAsync(map.values());
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    @Async
    public CompletableFuture<Map<String, Entity>> readAll() {
        return dao.getAllAsync().thenApply(map -> {
            storedEntities.set(map);
            return map;
        });
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "${cron}")
    public void refreshNow() {
        save();
        readAll();
    }

    public void addNewentity(Entity entity) {
        newEntities.getAndUpdate(map -> {
            map.put(entity.getHash(), entity);
            return map;
        });
    }

    public AtomicReference<List<Entity>> getStoredEntities() {
        return storedEntities.get().values();
    }

    public AtomicReference<List<Entity>> getNewEntities() {
        return newEntities.get().values();
    }
}
```

As I said, I need only keep data for some time, after by cron it will be flushed to db. I am interested in what is better approach - AR vs CHM ?

Comment: I would choose the one which seems simpler for your use case. Most likely the first one as that is what is usually used.

Comment: But I am interested in performance aspect. I couldn't find any proof regarding that

Comment: which performs better depends on your use case.  Unless you have measured this is a problem in your profiler for a realistic use case, I would assume it isn't the biggest problem you will have (or even in your top ten)

Comment: Use case is I add new items to map, after some time I just get items from map and flush to db, clear map.

Comment: I suspect neither is ideal.  You have to hold a lock when updating the map or when draining and swapping it.  I would use a lock `Object` and a plain `Map` possibly swapping it for another map when flushing.

Answer (score 9):

I'll start off by making the assumption that you require shared access to some resource, the temporary storage map, across multiple threads.

**The short answer:**

Use the ConcurrentHashMap.

**The long(er) answer:**

If your expectation is that through using an AtomicReference, you'll receive a consistent or thread-safe view of the map, or that your operations will be performed atomically, you're most likely to be incorrect - however, since you have not provided an example of your usage, I cannot say so with full certainty.

Whilst not negligible, performance shouldn't be the primary issue of your concern - rather, you should ensure the programs' ability  to perform correctly and as intended, and then seek to improve upon its performance.

If you have multiple threads reading from and / or writing to the temporary storage map, it's important that the internal state of the map remains consistent and correct; you can achieve this through implementing your operations in a manner that is [atomic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearizability) and thread-safe, and to that extent, both a [ConcurrentHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) or map wrapped by [SynchronizedMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap(java.util.Map)) will achieve this. However, each of the aforementioned implement their means of ensuring this at different granularities, and as a result of the specialised (optimistic) approach taken by the ConcurrentHashMap, as opposed to the naive (pessimistic) approach of the wrapped map, the ConcurrentHashMap is less susceptible to resource contention, and is likely to be the more performant of the two.

**Going Forward**

I've provided an implementation of the three mechanisms discussed in this post below; have an explore of the code below, in addition to the Java API documentation.

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;
import java.util.function.BiFunction;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class ConcurrencyExample {

    interface TemporaryStorage<K, V> {

        V compute(K key, BiFunction<? super K, ? super V, ? extends V> remapper);

        V put(K key, V value);

        V get(K key);

        void clear();

        @FunctionalInterface
        interface UnitTest<K, V> {

            void test(TemporaryStorage<K, V> store, K key);

        }

    }

    static class ConcurrentHashMapTS<K, V> implements TemporaryStorage<K, V> {

        private final Map<K, V> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

        @Override
        public V compute(K key, BiFunction<? super K, ? super V, ? extends V> remapper) {
            return map.compute(key, remapper);
        }

        @Override
        public V put(K key, V value) {
            return map.put(key, value);
        }

        @Override
        public V get(K key) {
            return map.get(key);
        }

        @Override
        public void clear() {
            map.clear();
        }
    }

    static class AtomicReferenceHashMapTS<K, V> implements TemporaryStorage<K, V> {

        private final AtomicReference<Map<K, V>> map = new AtomicReference<>(new HashMap<>());

        @Override
        public V compute(K key, BiFunction<? super K, ? super V, ? extends V> remapper) {
            return map.get().compute(key, remapper);
        }

        @Override
        public V put(K key, V value) {
            return map.get().put(key, value);
        }

        @Override
        public V get(K key) {
            return map.get().get(key);
        }

        @Override
        public void clear() {
            map.get().clear();
        }
    }

    static class MonitorLockedHashMapTS<K, V> implements TemporaryStorage<K, V> {

        private final Map<K, V> map = new HashMap<>();
        private final Object mutex = new Object(); // could use the map as the mutex

        @Override
        public V compute(K key, BiFunction<? super K, ? super V, ? extends V> remapper) {
            synchronized (mutex) {
                return map.compute(key, remapper);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public V put(K key, V value) {
            synchronized (mutex) {
                return map.put(key, value);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public V get(K key) {
            synchronized (mutex) {
                return map.get(key);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void clear() {
            synchronized (mutex) {
                map.clear();
            }
        }
    }

    static class WrappedHashMapTS<K, V> implements TemporaryStorage<K, V> {

        private final Map<K, V> map = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<>());

        @Override
        public V compute(K key, BiFunction<? super K, ? super V, ? extends V> remapper) {
            return map.compute(key, remapper);
        }

        @Override
        public V put(K key, V value) {
            return map.put(key, value);
        }

        @Override
        public V get(K key) {
            return map.get(key);
        }

        @Override
        public void clear() {
            map.clear();
        }
    }

    static class AtomicUnitTest implements TemporaryStorage.UnitTest<Integer, Integer> {

        @Override
        public void test(TemporaryStorage<Integer, Integer> store, Integer key) {
            store.compute(key, (k, v) -> (v == null ? 0 : v) + 1);
        }
    }

    static class UnsafeUnitTest implements TemporaryStorage.UnitTest<Integer, Integer> {

        @Override
        public void test(TemporaryStorage<Integer, Integer> store, Integer key) {
            Integer value = store.get(key);
            store.put(key, (value == null ? 0 : value) + 1);
        }
    }

    public static class TestRunner {

        public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException {
            final int iterations = 1_000;
            final List<Integer> keys = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, iterations).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());

            final int expected = iterations;

            for (int batch = 1; batch <= 5; batch++) {

                System.out.println(String.format("--- START BATCH %d ---", batch));

                test(System.out, new ConcurrentHashMapTS<>(), new AtomicUnitTest(), keys, expected, iterations);
                test(System.out, new ConcurrentHashMapTS<>(), new UnsafeUnitTest(), keys, expected, iterations);

                test(System.out, new AtomicReferenceHashMapTS<>(), new AtomicUnitTest(), keys, expected, iterations);
                test(System.out, new AtomicReferenceHashMapTS<>(), new UnsafeUnitTest(), keys, expected, iterations);

                test(System.out, new MonitorLockedHashMapTS<>(), new AtomicUnitTest(), keys, expected, iterations);
                test(System.out, new MonitorLockedHashMapTS<>(), new UnsafeUnitTest(), keys, expected, iterations);

                test(System.out, new WrappedHashMapTS<>(), new AtomicUnitTest(), keys, expected, iterations);
                test(System.out, new WrappedHashMapTS<>(), new UnsafeUnitTest(), keys, expected, iterations);

                System.out.println(String.format("--- END   BATCH %d ---", batch));

                System.out.println();

            }
        }

        private static <K, V> void test(PrintStream printer, TemporaryStorage<K, V> store, TemporaryStorage.UnitTest<K, V> work, List<K> keys, V expected, int iterations) throws InterruptedException {
            test(printer, store, work, keys, expected, iterations, Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() * 4);
        }

        private static <K, V> void test(PrintStream printer, TemporaryStorage<K, V> store, TemporaryStorage.UnitTest<K, V> work, List<K> keys, V expected, int iterations, int parallelism) throws InterruptedException {
            final ExecutorService workers = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(parallelism);
            final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

            for (K key : keys) {
                for (int iteration = 1; iteration <= iterations; iteration++) {

                    workers.execute(() -> {
                        try {
                            work.test(store, key);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            //e.printStackTrace(); //thrown by the AtomicReference<Map<K, V>> implementation
                        }
                    });

                }
            }

            workers.shutdown();
            workers.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.DAYS);

            final long finish = System.currentTimeMillis();

            final DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("###,###");

            final long correct = keys.stream().filter(key -> expected.equals(store.get(key))).count();

            printer.println(String.format("Store '%s' performed %s iterations of %s across %s threads in %sms. Accuracy: %d / %d (%4.2f percent)", store.getClass().getSimpleName(), formatter.format(iterations), work.getClass().getSimpleName(), formatter.format(parallelism), formatter.format(finish - start), correct, keys.size(), ((double) correct / keys.size()) * 100));
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: This is not valid, compiling Java code. Java has no `val` or `fun` keywords, and neither `override`.

Comment: This is Kotlin code (should have specified that) which can be executed on the JVM.

Comment: I suspected as much, but the question is tagged in Java. Code should either specify that it is pseudo-code or should be posted in the language the question i asked in. if you are programming in java, this code example simply will not compile unless you install a Kotlin compiler.

Comment: Good point; I'll write and post the equivalent code in Java by the end of the day, I should have taken that into account when responding, but instead decided to respond using my preferred language - thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Guys, I've added code sample of how it looks like now

Comment: @Polygnome Updated with roughly equivalent Java code!